# Supporting Multiple Screen Sizes - Determining programmatically

Tags: android

So I have my layouts created, via this section on Android:
http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

This issue occurs where, because of the additional screen real estate the sw720dp has several objects that the standard, and even the sw600dp do not include. The different layouts all load correctly, but when I'm actually handling the activities I don't know how to determine which of the layouts is in use (so I cannot hook the extra buttons, etc.). What is the best method to use to determine this?

Comment: I'm not sure how reliable it would be but you could try `getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(...)` then check the `densityDpi` field of the `DisplayMetrics`. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/DisplayMetrics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest method would be to check if `findViewById` returns a non-null value before hooking up your UI elements.

Comment: beat me by 10 seconds... im trying for 20k today.

Answer (score 2):

I usually use `Button b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);` then check if the button is null, if it's null that means it's not there and i cant use it.

Answer (score 2):

From the Android Training class on [Designing for Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html#TaskUseOriQuali).

Define a value in res/values/layout.xml res/values-sw600dp/layout.xml, res/values-sw720dp/layout.xml, etc, that just sets a boolean, "hasExtraStuff".  The value will change depending on which layout folder loads (just like your layouts), and you can check that value once at the beginning of the run of your application.